# Parse Error:Syntax Error T_String

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, php

I have ubuntu as guest on virtualbox and host is Windows 7 ultimate.
phpinfo(); in test.php at /var/www/ displays the proper information, yet
when I echo something out, I receive : Parse Error:Syntax error unexpected 'blah' T_String.
charset is set in /php5/apache2/php.ini and also I add it in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf via AddDefaultCharset.
Kian William

Comment: Syntax error means your code is incorrect. Kindly edit your question and include your actual echo code.

Comment: The code is one line: <?php echo "hello world"; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Everything works now. When I installed ubuntu on virtual box, I set the language settings as English UK (old international ...), I changed it to English US. The problem was not with php or lamp at all. It was with the language settings.
Kian William Nowrouzian